# VueJS 2 can't emit event in mounted(), created() hooks

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Out of the blue, emitter stopped working:

event-bus.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

```js
import { EventBus } from '../event-bus';

...

mounted() {
  this.getCart();
}

...

methods: {
      getCart() {
        axios.get(`${app.api_erp_url}/cart/${this.cartId}`).then((response) => {
          this.cart = response.data;
          EventBus.$emit('cartLoaded', this.cart); // this not working
        });
      }
},
```

another-component.vue

```js
mounted() {
      // MiniCart.vue
      EventBus.$on('cartLoaded', (payload) => {
        ...
      });
    },
```

No matter how I try to emit the event inside `mounted`/`created`, it will not work. No problems when firing events on click or something.

Created sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-kilby-m43ih?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: put debugger one line above - check EventBus events array - if empty other component hasnt registered anything yet, if debugger never triggers axios throws

Comment: Are you sure there is no `error` in `axios.get`?

Comment: Yes I'm sure: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-kilby-m43ih?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @RamkatLTU Try adding listener in `created:hook` not `mouted`. I have a feeling that your `$on` might not be "in place" before `event` is `$emitted`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Child components mount [**before**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52434057/6277151) their parent component.

This is the sequence occurring in your example:

1. `HelloWorld` (parent) is created
2. `Test` (child) is created
3. `Test` (child) is mounted, which emits an event
4. `HelloWorld` (parent) is mounted, which subscribes to the event that was already emitted

If you want `HelloWorld` to catch the event from its children, subscribe to the event in the `created` hook.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/subscribing-to-child-events-jqrh2?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:293-307)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names) You should use `kebab-case` format to name your custom events :

```
EventBus.$emit('cartLoaded', this.cart);//not correct

EventBus.$emit('cart-loaded', this.cart); //correct
```

Comment: This is a good practice but it should work even with `camelCase`. The compilier change it anyway.

Comment: @AdamOrlov it's the only correct syntax, please check this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names

Comment: "For these reasons, we recommend you always use kebab-case for event names." Still good practice, not "only correct syntax".

Comment: I actually use camelCase and it working for other events, anyway changed to kebab-case still same problem.

Comment: it's weird, could provide a sample code in codesandbox?

Comment: I will try, what is super strange that getCart is actually sending request and receiving data.

Comment: Try to enrich this https://codesandbox.io/s/q9r70817vj

Comment: Already created: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-kilby-m43ih?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @RamkatLTU Try adding listener in `created:hook`

Comment: @RomkaLTU the issue happened when you emit an event from lifecycle hook, if you add a handler that runs emit this will work https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-wing-e1z44?file=/src/components/Test.vue

Answer (score 0):

May be the event emitted  before MiniCart.vue component registered the event.

Meaning in code.

```
  EventBus.$emit('cartLoaded', this.cart);
```

this run first time before the event has been registered

```
EventBus.$on('cartLoaded', (payload) => {
        ...
      });
```